# Is it a good practice to implement a singleton-like class using class attributes?

Tags: python, oop, singleton

I have a class that contains some variables/states.
I would like to share those states with many other classes in my code.
I looked online and I saw that modules and singleton classes are a good way to this. I ended up creating a class and storing all the data as class attributes and accessing it via the class it self, like the example:

```
# foo.py
class Foo(object):
  varx=45
  def foo(x):
    Foo.varx = x
```

And I would import the data as:

```
# bar.py
from foo import Foo
print(Foo.varx) #45
Foo.foo(5)
print(Foo.varx) #5
```

I would like to know if using classes attributes like this is an anti-pattern, or if there is a downside I am not seeing in this implementation.

Comment: While in my opinion generally speaking it would be OK, many languages have other mechanisms to accomplish the same thing. For example, C/C++ has header files. In Python I would recommend using a module, dictionary, or namespace instead.

Comment: I think it would be ok. But, there are a few ways to change the attribute, you should give it some restrictions whereby it can only be changed via `.foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `foo` method is altering the state of the *class* `Foo` (rather than the state of any one *instance* of  `Foo`), it would be more pythonic to use a `classmethod` in this case. Also, note that there is no need to explicitly inherit from `object`, as all python classes implicitly inherit from `object`.

```
class Foo:
    varx = 45

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, x):
        cls.varx = x
```

Your current implementation of the `foo` method has the name of the class hardcoded into the implementation, which means that the implementation would break if you changed the name of the class. The implementation would also break if you had another class inheriting from `Foo` which you wanted to be able to implement the methods of `Foo`, as the class inheriting from `Foo` would have a different name.